# Which libraries/frameworks in Java rely on client-defined classes to have static members?

Tags: java, static-members

There are libraries and frameworks in Java that rely on static members in the class. Usually, they inspect certain static fields of the class via reflection.

As example, I know that `AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater`s usually need to be saved in a static field of the class it is modifying, if put in another class they will lack a security permission to do it.

My questions are:

1. Can you list dominant Java frameworks/libraries that rely on certain static fields being present in the class? In what way?
2. Are there any important Java frameworks/libraries which rely on the presence of static **methods** in the class?

Comment: Wait...what do you mean, "rely on"?  There are lots of libraries that provide static methods.  Or are you referring only to libraries that expect classes to be organized a certain way, using reflection?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I meant - libraries/frameworks which inspect the presence of static fields/methods at runtime via reflection. Or require that some object is kept in a static field of the class, for reasons of, say, security permissions (such as `AtomicReferenceUpdater`s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring 3.1's JUnit support will inspect the test class's static nested classes, to find an annotated configuration class. But I wouldn't say it relies on it; it's purely an example of convention over configuration.

JUnit also relies on static methods for its `@BeforeClass` and similar annotations.

In both cases the static members need to be annotated.

Answer (score 3):

Just comes to my mind:
Whenever a client class must implement Serializable it relies on `serialVersionUID` static field.